# Retrofit 2. Как получить результат как JSONObject

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

У меня есть ответ с сервер json-строка вида:

```
{"data":{объект данных},
 "error":{объект ошибки}}
```

Пример:

> {"data":null,"error":{"message":"Не указан код активации.","type":1}}

Я формирую класс ответа.
Проблема в том, что "объект ошибки" может быть любой структуры и я хочу его получать как JSONObject.

```
public class Envelope<T> {
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private T data;

@SerializedName("error")
@Expose
private JSONObject error;
...
```

Вызов:

```
Call<Envelope<User>> call = 
        service.registerDevice("registerDevice", pass, imei);
call.enqueue(new MyCallback<Envelope<User>>(idRequest, responseListener));
```

Comment: а почему именно как объект если не секрет? ведь можно установить фильтры при неудовлетворительном ответе и действовать согласно этому фильтру.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, а что вы подразумеваете под фильтрами? Я в принципе согласен и на строку - преобразовать в JSON не проблема. Но тут получается весь ответ как строка должен быть.

Comment: ну можно сделать так что тело ответа будет просматриваться в случае неудачного ответа, и дальше можно будет сделать поиск подстроки в теле сообщения

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, а можно пример? А то сообразить не могу.

Comment: добавил ответ к вашему вопросу

Comment: `JSONObject` - это тип из Android SDK и, вероятно, `Gson` конвертер не может с ним работать. Пробуйте заменить на `JsonObject` (из комплекта самой библиотеки).

Comment: @woesss Класс. Сразу заработало. остался нюанс - если в результате пришло "error":null - выдает ошибку.

Comment: @woesss. решил проблему: обернул в отдельный класс и стало возвращать нормально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@woesss написал правильное решение:

> JSONObject - это тип из Android SDK и, вероятно, Gson конвертер не может с ним работать. Пробуйте заменить на JsonObject (из комплекта самой библиотеки).

Есть проблема, решается дополнительным обертыванием:

```
public class ResponseError {
  @SerializedName("data")
  @Expose
  private JsonObject data;
```

Если  в ответ приходит `data:null`, то выпадает ошибка. Не может null преобразовать в `JsonObject`.

Решение:

```
private JsonObjectWrapper data;
...
public class JsonObjectWrapper {
   private JsonObject jsonObject;
//Getters & Setters
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

вот к примеру как можно ловить ошибки:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    } else {
                        ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                        try {
                            if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("refresh_token_expired")) {
                                logOut();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

может подойдет, если нет то будем дальше думать :)

Comment: Я так ответ и обрабатываю в callback-е. Другое дело, что сюда уже не приходит, ошибка конвертации или пустой объект.

Comment: а в логах что-то есть? в основном все должно работать красиво и правильно